# How to read response body in WAI middleware?

Tags: haskell, middleware, haskell-wai

I'm trying to create some middleware that will send 500 errors to a remote server. The error information is in the response body.

How can I get the response body from a `Response` as any kind of string? I see [`responseToStream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:responseToStream) but I can't figure out how to use it.

```
import Network.Wai
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)

responseBody :: Response -> IO ByteString
responseBody res = _
```

Comment: The result of `responseToStream` is a 3-tuple; I'm guessing by "body" you mean you are interested in the 3rd component and not the first two (which are concrete, i.e. non-abstract, algebraic types, so you can access their fields directly). For the 3rd comp, you could probably just pass a function for `Builder -> IO ()` which `mappend`s each `Builder` to an `IORef` (or `MVar` in a concurrent setting) - "the first parameter provides a means of sending another chunk of data" (here 'sending' is just saving in memory).

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of the comment by @user2407038:

```
import Data.IORef (newIORef,modifyIORef',readIORef)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import Data.ByteString.Builder (toLazyByteString)

import Network.Wai

responseBody :: Response -> IO ByteString
responseBody res =
  let (status,headers,body) = responseToStream res in
  body $ \f -> do
    content <- newIORef mempty
    f (\chunk -> modifyIORef' content (<> chunk)) (return ())
    toLazyByteString <$> readIORef content
```